# How can I maintain the cursor in the same cell after entering a value in it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which requires only one value to be entered into cell C2 in order to re-calculate all the other cells. How can I keep the cursor from leaving cell C2 after entering a value into it and preventing the user from altering any other cells?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlock the cell(s) you want users to be able to change. Protect the sheet, and uncheck the "allow users to select locked cells" checkbox.